# Android plugin 2.2.3: No tests found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-testing, android-uiautomator

After upgrading Android gradle plugin version I have faced an issue that tests in my project were not found.

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'application.sample.id'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

}
```

And the error that I am having:

```
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[emulator-name-23_x86(AVD) - 6.0] [31mFAILED [0m
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
:TestLauncher:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
```

Comment: I've also experienced that. Cleaning project resolves the issue.

Comment: @azizbekian, thanks. I have already tried it :(

Comment: are you trying to run the tests on a real device or emulator? what is the Android version?

Comment: @Gustavo, emulator, linux, Android 23.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and I can't get rid of it. It was working for a very short time after commenting out sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    } from my build.gradle (app) file, but after some codechanges it started acting up again. This makes it impossible to use jacoco for testcoverage. Have you found an answer yet?

Comment: Hi @Bohsen. Mostly this happens when exceptions are thrown in `@BeforeClass` method. Yes, really. But sometimes issue is reproduced with no reason